# How to compare two, time based, measurements of the same object

Tags: mathematical-statistics, measurement-error, measurement

I have 2 rounds of measurements from a set of 10 capacitors. The measurements are with respect to frequency and are all measured at the same 200 frequencies between 1 kHz and 5 MHz. The data is not normally distributed. The data we got differed from cap to cap so we decided to remeasure a second time. How can I compare these two measurements to show that the oddities were on the manufacturing side and not due to bad measurements. Essentially, how can I show that the second measurement is statistically similar to the first?

Answer (score 1):

You have $10 \times 200 = 2000$ pairs of test results. So you could find the 2000 differences.

My 1st step would be to look at those differences. If their mean (or median) is not significantly different from 0 [per one-sample t (or Wilcoxon) test], then you can be pretty sure important differences you're seeing in farads are mostly due to differences among capacitors.
You might want to stop there.

Then if you want to go further, you could do a 2-way ANOVA on the differences.
Factor 1 has 10 levels corresponding to 10 capacitors; we wonder if there
are significant differences among them. I suppose these are randomly chosen capacitors and not of particular individual interest, so I probably wouldn't do ad hoc tests.

Factor 2 is frequencies (100 levels). It seems you already know they will have
significant differences in capacitance, but including this factor in the ANOVA model (as a 'blocking factor') helps to make the test for differences among capacitors more powerful.

There are two important assumptions for the ANOVA procedure. (i) Roughly equal variances among capacitors and among frequencies. You should test for that.
(ii) Roughly normal residuals from the ANOVA model. You should make a normal probability plot to make sure it roughly linear. If not, you might do a Friedman test on Capacitors with Frequencies as blocks. The test would give only a P-value for capacitors.